# Abort / timeout : request has been aborted manually or because of the conection timeout. No response from the server but the connection wasn't closed

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, web-services, sqlite

I created a web service in which my android developer hit a Url to get some data in Json format from server database .It works well but sometimes it gives"Abort / timeout". As my user increased it is creating problem for me and my android app in which this service is used.Please help me out.

Abort / timeout

The request has been aborted manually or because of the conection timeout. There were no response from the server but the connection wasn't closed.

Answer (score 1):

there is default time expiry of 30 seconds for http response,
so if it is then your android developer would get abort/timeout if your service takes more than 30 second(like when network slow or for some other dependency "it is you sometime case when he is getting abort/timeout"),
 you can extend it  from your config file